# Defining a distance between images

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let's consider raster images represented by bi dimensional real matrices. I have an original image $M_0$, and after transforming it several times I get a set of related images $M_n$, which have the same size (as in height and width) but may or may not have the same resolution than $M_0$ (i.e. they're not scaled the same way).

I want to find a way to sort those images from how "close" they are to the original image $M_0$. How can I define a distance between images that would lead to an interesting/meaningful comparison ?

If they had the same resolution, I could simply, for instance, sum the square of the difference of the colors for each pixel, but it's not that simple when the resolutions differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that every pixel covers a finite rectangle of a given size (the same size for all rectangles in a given resolution, but the size would decrease with increasing resolution). Define your picture as a block function that is constant on each rectangle (I am treating the grayscale case but it is easily generalised to colours).

The distance between two pictures is the square root of the integral of the squared difference of these functions. Since every rectangle of one picture overlaps with a finite number of rectangles from the other, this integral is actually a finite sum.